# How to reduce nodes from a cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I searched everywhere on how to reduce the number of minion nodes that you have in your cluster after following this guide

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/gce/

`kubectl drain`, `kubectl delete node <nodename>`, and manually deleting the virtual machines still causes the nodes to spawn back up again.

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud compute instance-groups managed resize kubernetes-minion-group --size=42`

The variable size is how many worker/minion nodes you would like in your cluster